# Eclipse Won't Load My Workspace Contents

Tags: eclipse

I recently deleted an account I was using on my Mac (Mavericks if means anything, although it shouldn't). I was using that account to run eclipse and saved all my files on a disc image before deleting. I took all the files and switched them into my current workspace but now they don't show up in the package explorer(although I can access them from My Documents). Can someone please tell how to make them show up in the panel? It's getting very time consuming to constantly have to open them through Docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are in projects that Eclipse does not know about you need to do `File / Import... / General / Existing Projects into Workspace`.

If the files are in existing projects use `File / Refresh` to get Eclipse to pick up the new files.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, you can always try recreating your project and then adding all the classes and other files through the file menu, add existing item.  This way you can maintain the integrity of your project withouth having to change any of the packages or classes inheritance.

Hope this helps.